# Find abscissa of intersection of graphs

Tags: analysis

Determine the X coordinate of the points in which the graphs of the functions
$f, \: g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, $
$$f(x) = x^6  \:\: \text{and} \: \: g(x) = 2x^5 -2x - 1$$
are tangent.

I tried forming the equation $$x^6 - 2x^5 + 2x + 1 = 0 $$
and derivate it but I have found nothing relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: your polynomial can be written as $$(x^2-x-1)^2(x^2+1)=x^6-2x^5+2x+1$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got to that form, please ? (Like,how did you group the terms ?)

Comment: divide your polynomial by $$x-i$$ and $$x+i$$

Answer (score 2):

The two curves are tangent if they intersect in a point with multiplicity 2
Thus the equation $x^6=2 x^5 - 2 x - 1$ must have double roots, as $x=1$ is a double root of $(x-1)^2=0$

Consider the equation
$$x^6-2 x^5+2 x+1=0$$
It must be factored as
$$(x - a)^2 (x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2  + d x + e)$$
Expanding we get

$x^3 \left(a^2 b-2 a c+d\right)+x^4 \left(a^2-2 a b+c\right)+x^2 \left(a^2 c-2 a d+e\right)+x \left(a^2 d-2 a e\right)+a^2 e+x^5 (b-2 a)+x^6$

Which must be identical to $x^6-2 x^5+2 x+1$ that is coefficients must be the same

$a^2 e = 1, a^2 d - 2 a e = 2, a^2 c - 2 a d + e = 
  0, a^2 b - 2 a c + d = 0, a^2 - 2 a b + c = 
  0, -2 a + b = -2$

This system needs to be solved just for $a$ and we get

$a_1=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right);\;a_2=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)$

which are the two double roots of the equation.